# jCarousel animate the carousel with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Hi I'm using jCarousel. Is it possible to animate the carousel yourself. So for example I could create a button and attach a jQuery handler to it so that when the button was click it moved the carousel to a certain index?

Answer (score 2):

```
var carousel = $('element_you_called_jcarousel_on').data('jcarousel');
carousel.scroll(index); //moves to a specified index (1-n);
carousel.next(); //move forward 1 item
carousel.prev(); //move back 1 item
```